# How to conditionally prevent an include file from being executed with Progress ABL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

To those who know,

How does one conditionally prevent an include from being executed in Progress ABL? Is that even possible? If not what do you purpose?

Based on user selection - here is an example:

If checkBox = yes then
    {randomInclude.i}
Else 
"Do remaining things"

Comment: You probably want to wrap a DO: ... END. pair around that.  But otherwise that is pretty much what you would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to share the code of your include file to make your request clearer to us.

TheDrooper's answer shows how to do it based on a compile time condition. Your sample seems to be based on a runtime solution. In that case I'd do:

```
If checkBox = yes then do:
    {randomInclude.i} 
end.
Else do:
    "Do remaining things"
end.
```

The do-block is required as you just don't know how many statement are inside the include file.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an include file in your program, the contents of the include are placed in your program at that position. In your example, whatever is in randominclude.i is stuck in the "then" condition. As Tom said, you probably just need to wrap it in a DO-END block. You can also put that in the include file.

You can also conditionally include a file at compile time. Suppose this is the contents of randominclude.i:

```
MESSAGE "Included" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
```

You can define a preprocessor in your program to add the include:

```
&SCOPED-DEFINE UseIt

&IF DEFINED(UseIt) &THEN
    {randominclude.i}
&ENDIF
```

Run that and you'll get an "Included" pop-up message. But change the preprocessor to this:

```
&SCOPED-DEFINE DontUseIt
```

Run the program now and nothing will happen because "UseIt" is no longer defined so randominclude.i is not included in the program.

Comment: Just a note on that: When using multiple include files and nesting them - I'd suggest to use a &GLOBAL-DEFINE for UseIt and not a &SCOPED-DEFINE. GLOBAL-DEFINEs can be defined inside an include file too and remain valid up the stack. SCOPED-DEFINEs are just valid inside the file they are defined and all include file defined form there.

Comment: Also remember that preprocessors are just preprocessors. So if you compile in one environment (for instance a build server) and then run on a separate server you need to make sure that those enviroments look the same and include the same way. A typical example that could fail would be compile time checks for Linux/Win-environments.