# Variable file name for an include file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have an application using Openedge that has 3 environments: live, test and training. I’ve inherited a number of 4GL programs that need to be converted from a legacy version of the application that uses include files. The include files currently reside in a shared directory but will need to be placed in directories specific to the environment for the new version I’m working with (/live/files, /test/files, /train/files). Is there a valid function to set the include file with a variable file name?

I have a way to query the environment name in the 4GL code to set the path but using VALUE() in the include statement doesn’t work.  The output mentioned not being able to find a file name called VALUE().

Comment: Take a look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900563/how-to-conditionally-prevent-an-include-file-from-being-executed-with-progress-a). It deals with conditioning the inclusion of a file.

Comment: No, you cannot use a variable or a function for the name of the include file. James' answer (use PROPATH) is the most general but, depending on what the includes actually do and why they might be different from environment to environment, there might be alternative approaches. You'd have to tell us more about the code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this in my opinion would be to add /live, /test, /train to the PROPATH in that environment. Then you can reference the include file with files/filename.i.

Answer (score 0):

Put the INCLUDE files on their respective folder.

After that there is two possible solutions:

1. If you are using a custom .INI, open the file and set the root path of the .I directory in the **"PROPATH="**.
   For Example: `PROPATH=E:\live\source,E:\live\source\includefiles`
   Propath folders are only set on the folder itself, not on folders inside of them (Needs to be set manually)
2. If you don't have a **.INI** file, navigate to your Progress instalation folder and duplicate the `progress.ini` from the **BIN folder**. After this, add the settings from **Item 1** and add the `-ini "c:\path_to_ini\progress.ini"` into the program shortcut.

One thing that you need to know is that the PROPATH will search for the first file in the included folders. For example, if you have two programs with the same name in **source** and **includefiles**, the program will run only the first one.

For the different enviroments folder, just use different .INI files.

After this, just use `{includeFile.i}` to call the INCLUDE file and it will get the first-find from the PROPATH variables.
`{includeFile.i}` call cannot include the path in the name and neither being called with VALUES().